# QGIS crashes when setting new Symbol to layer with python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I followed the `QGIS 3` cookbook and created a new custom symbol layer class. But when I try to create a new the symbol, `QGIS` crashes. I create it like this.

```py
symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol({FooMarker(20)})
```

The link for the cookbook is the following: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/pdf/en/QGIS-testing-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf page: 31

My `FooMarker` class looks like this.

```
class FooMarker(QgsMarkerSymbolLayer):
    def __init__(self, radius=4.0):
        QgsMarkerSymbolLayer.__init__(self)
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = QColor(255,0,0)

    def layerType(self):
        return "FooMarker"

    def properties(self):
        return {"radius": str(self.radius)}

    def startRender(self, context):
        pass

    def stopRender(self, context):
        pass

   def renderPoint(self, point, context):
        color = context.selectionColor() if context.selected() else self.color
        p = context.renderContext().painter()
        p.setPen(color)
        p.drawEllipse(point, self.radius, self.radius)

    def clone(self):
        return FooMarker(self.radius)
```

Comment: One problem is curly brackets. If QGIS keeps crashing after changing {} into [], that means you have different issue with code. As it's currently written (one line of code), it’s hard to tell exactly what problem is. Add extra explanation/code etc. to your question. You can add `class FooMarker` block, for example. Maybe the problem is within the class body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [QGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMarkerSymbol.html#a53c8e6f56454d31bea42c384ea358bbe) `QgsMarkerSymbol` class needs `QgsSymbolLayerList`. That means a `list` in Python.

> `QgsMarkerSymbol (const QgsSymbolLayerList & layers = QgsSymbolLayerList())`

But you pass a dictionary to `QgsMarkerSymbol` constructor method. If you change `{FooMarker(20)}` into `[FooMarker(20)]`, QGIS doesn't crash.

Comment: Well that makes sense and I changed it but QGIS still crashes.

Comment: In QGIS 3.2.1, when I run `symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol([FooMarker(20)])`, QGIS doesn't crash. Are you sure you encounter crashing because of that line (`symbol = ...`)